# How to update outer class attributes whenever inner class attributes change?

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

I have a nested class, and I'd like to update an attribute of the outer class whenever an attribute of the inner class is changed.
**Here's a minimal example:**

```py
class Outer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.statements = {}

    def add_statement(self, str_one, str_two):
        inner = self.Inner(self, str_one, str_two)
        self.statements[inner] = inner.sum
        return inner

    class Inner:
        def __init__(self, outer_inst, str_one, str_two):
            self.outer_inst = outer_inst
            self.str_one = str_one
            self.str_two = str_two

        @property
        def sum(self):
            return self.str_one + self.str_two
```

The code basically updates `statements` upon creation of an inner class using `add_statement`.

```py
>>> outer = Outer()
>>> inner = outer.add_statement("Hi", "Dog")
>>> inner.sum
"HiDog"
>>> outer.statements[inner]
"HiDog"
```

However, suppose I want to write `inner.str_one = "Bye"` instead. Then

```py
>>> inner.str_one = "Bye"
>>> inner.sum 
"ByeDog"
>>> outer.statements[inner]
"HiDog"
```

The problem here is that `outer.statements` does not update. For my actual code, which really does require nested classes, I'd like for it to update (take my word that this behavior is desirable for my desired construction). **Thus, how do I find a way to update the outer class attribute whenever the inner attributes change?**

Comment: What if you call `create_inner` twice and have two `Inner` instances… which one should `Outer` correspond to then…?

Comment: It consistently corresponds to both? Updating either one updates the other.

Comment: `i1 = outer.create_inner(...); i2 = outer.create_inner(...); i1.str_one = '1'; i2.str_one = '2'; outer.my_str` — Now what?

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood your question. This isn't what I'm actually doing in my code so it appears I simplified the MWE too much. Let me fix that.

Comment: Basically, there's a dictionary in the Outer class, whose keys and values depend on creation of instances of the inner class. The dictionary needs to be updated whenever one of the instances of the inner class are.

Answer (score 0):

Since I figured it out, I thought I'd share it in case it is useful to anyone else. With the code below, any updates to any of the outer classes will automatically update `Outer.my_dict`. It basically requires a dummy private variable `_my_dict`. Perhaps there's a better way, but since it's downvoted we'll never know.

```py
class Outer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_dict = {}

    @property
    def my_dict(self):
        statement_dict = {}
        for inner_obj in self._my_dict:
            statement_dict[inner_obj] = inner_obj.sum
        return statement_dict

    @my_dict.setter
    def my_dict(self, val):
        self._my_dict[val] = val.sum

    def create_inner(self, str_one, str_two):
        inner = self.Inner(self, str_one, str_two)
        self._my_dict[inner] = inner.sum
        return inner

    class Inner:
        def __init__(self, outer_inst, str_one, str_two):
            self.outer_inst = outer_inst
            self.str_one = str_one
            self.str_two = str_two

        @property
        def sum(self):
            return self.str_one + self.str_two
```

Observe that...

```py
>>> outer = Outer()
>>> inner = outer.create_inner("Hi", "Dog")
>>> outer.my_dict.values()
dict_values(['HiDog'])
>>> inner.str_one = "Bye"
>>> outer.my_dict.values()
dict_values(['ByeDog'])
```